# Facebook Login Error iOS Application

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, testflight

My iOS application allows me to login using my own facebook account successfully. But when I send it on test flight to a friend, the app downloads but when he presses connect to Facebook (which works on my simulator and personal device), it won't let him log in. Doesn't even give him the option to, just spits out an error (com.facebook.sdk error 2). What am I missing? What would cause it to work for me, but not for others? I'm just looking for a general answer here because I followed all the facebook tutorials and I can't imagine what kind of thing could be going wrong.

Comment: What is the BundleId in facebook for your app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just figured out the problem. Should have been SUPER obvious, but being new to development I didn't realize I needed to change the sandbox setting to disabled in order to allow others to access facebook through my app.

Answer (score 0):

This error pops up when your app is not authenticated properly.

You need to keep your BundleId the same at all places.

Change your bundleId in the app that you have registered on Facebook as com.asdad.casd instead of < teamId >.com.asdad.casd

Comment: Thanks, I have checked that my bundle ID is identical in all places and it is. This does not fix it though. Do you have any other thoughts on what the problem could be?

Comment: Do you use this? FBSessionStateChangedNotification in your delegate? Check what bundleId is being sent there

Comment: Also, if you have asked for `offline_access` permission and if the permission is not set.

Comment: thanks! i just figured out it was the sandbox setting, but I appreciate the suggestions.